# Nginx trailing slash rewrite not working

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I have a site that uses subdirectories and currently only works when the trailing slash is added to the URL ("http://www.domain.com/dir/"). When there is no trailing slash, I get "unable to connect at server domain.com:8080" (8080 is the listening port Nginx is set up for).

I've tried adding the rewrite suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645853/add-slash-to-the-end-of-every-url-need-rewrite-rule-for-nginx) (and [here](http://www.osbmedia.com/blog/view/adding-a-trailing-slash-to-your-urls-on-nginx)), but it results in the "cannot connect" error for the entire virtual host.

Is there another way to add the trailing slash that I could try? Or, is there a way I can configure it to see the URL as a directory (and thus, look for the index file), regardless of the presence of the trailing slash?

Answer (score 0):

I too tried but i dint find proper solution. But you can try forceful passing to backend. If www.domain.com/dir comes it should go to backend 127.0.0.1:8080/dir

location /dir {

```
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

              proxy_set_header Host $host;

        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/dir;
  }
```

Comment: The key that I want/need is for it to go to www.domain.com/dir**/** when www.domain.com/dir is typed in. This works on my local server, which uses port 80, but not my live one, which is using port 8080.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I'm getting you wrong, but linking a file to the `sites-enabled` nginx directory with the following content replaces `host.tld/gls` with `host.tld/gls/` for me if I connect to the former.

```
server {
    location /gls {
        root   /var/www/;
     }
}
```